# Added Android NDK to project and `OS independent path error`

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, aac

I am trying to add a `Android NDK` to my project in `Android Studio`. The project I am trying to add can be found here : https://github.com/timsu/android-aac-enc

I have added the `JNI` folder to the root of my project and It seems to recognize it, but when I build the project I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libaac-encoder.so'
```

I have also tried adding these lines but when using these or deleting I get 16 more errors so It seems the that the `Android aac enc` is not the only thing using `lib/armeabi-v7a/libaac-encoder.so`:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libaac-encoder.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libaac-encoder.so'

    }
```

If there is anything else that I need to provide then I will do so. I just do not seem to understand where this error is coming from.

I have looked in all of my folders and none of them have another `libaac-encoder.so`.

There were no errors before  I moved the `JNI` folder from the project to mine.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio v3.2 or newer, copying the JNI folder is not enough.

You should add

```
android { externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild {
    path 'jni/Android.mk'
} } }
```

Comment: I did not mention it but I do already have that line. Is there anything else I could provide that could be of use in order for you to help me?

Comment: My guess is when I added the `JNI` it came or created `libaac-encoder.so` but my project was already using it, since when I remove it, then It gives me many more errors and now they are both trying to use their own and that gives the error, but I have no idea how to check it or fix it

Comment: It's very hard to guess what goes wrong when you withhold important details. If you want your issue to be resolved quickly and completely,  reproduce the problem in a minimal way (remove all irrelevant code as long as the issue is reproduced), and post the full failing code here or on GitHub.